# How to merge Payment method and Order review in checkout process for Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to reduce checkout process so I think reduce checkout process by merge

1. Payment method and order review
2. Billing Information and Shipping Information
   (There is only add Shipping information by customer and give a checkbox of     "**Same as Billing Information**" )

I used Magento 1.9.2. I seen many solutions but its not work properly.Please give me any idea for this concept.

Comment: You can use iwd onestep checkout so taht we can easily manage all easily.

Comment: I used but there is only one button Place order and I want to 3 Buttons like as simple checkout process.

Comment: You can customize as par your need